# Show that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} xf'(x)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, derivatives

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$. Suppose $f$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$ and its derivative is continuous on $(0,1)$. Then is it true that
$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} xf'(x)=0 \ ?$$

I only thought about functions like $x^{a}$ for $a>0$. It seems to be true. Indeed, in fact if we assume $f'$ is monotonically decreasing and non negative then $$0\le xf'(x) \le \int_0^x f'(t) \, dt = f(x)-f(0)$$
But I am not sure how to do it generally. Any help suggestions?

Comment: @SameerBaheti is $\ln x$ continuous at $0$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. Consider the function $$f(x) =\begin{cases}
x\sin(\frac{1}{x})\hspace{4mm}x > 0 \\
0 \hspace{17mm}x = 0\end{cases}$$
Then on $(0,1)$ we have $f'(x) = \sin(\frac{1}{x}) -\frac{1}{x}\cos(\frac{1}{x})$. Hence $$ \lim_{x\to0^+}xf'(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}x\sin\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)-\cos\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big) = DNE$$
So the limit does not even exist.

Comment: Is its derivative continuous?

Comment: It is on $(0,1)$

Comment: yes it is continuous on $(0,1)$. very nice example

Comment: Ah! Should have thought about this kind of function!

Comment: @AndrewShedlock Isn't its derivative rapidly changing near $x=0$ and therefore not continuous? Please elaborate.

Comment: @SameerBaheti the derivative is changing rapidly and changes even more rapidly as we get close to $0$. But at every point $x>0$, the function is well defined and is in fact a smooth function. This example highlights, that just because a function is nice in an open set, doesn't mean the function is nice as it approaches its boundary.

Comment: After revising some definitions, I have concluded that it wouldn't have been differentiable, and its derivative wouldn't have been continuous if it was defined for $x\in(-\infty,+\infty)$. Here, since here it is defined just for $x\in(0,+\infty)$, it is a nice function. Do you think I got it?

Comment: It would not be continuously differentiable everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$, that is correct. But it is fine because it is defined on $(0,\infty)$

Comment: Why would you put an "equals" sign before "DNE"? I thought that (or writing that abbreviation) was done only by confused sophomores.

Answer (score 1):

No, consider $f(x)=\lvert x\rvert^{3/2}\sin x^{-2}$, which has $$f'(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x=0\\ \frac{3\lvert x\rvert^{3/2}}{2x}\sin x^{-2}-\frac{2\lvert x\rvert^{3/2}}{x^3}\cos x^{-2}&\text{if }x\ne 0\end{cases}$$ and therefore $\limsup_{x\to 0^+}xf'(x)=\infty$ and $\liminf_{x\to 0^+}xf'(x)=-\infty$.